# Finding an expression/approximation of this product

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I'm trying to find an expression for $\prod_{j=1}^n\left(j-\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}+1\right)$ in terms of n. I have tried finding $\int_1^n\ln\left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+1\right)\,dx$ by parts but end up with a big mess. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In fact, the value of the last integral is quite negligible for an approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you wrote, the calculation of $$I_n=\int_1^n\ln\left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+1\right)\,dx$$ is not the most pleasant one.

Using, as you did, integration by parts, we have
$$\int\ln\left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+1\right)\,dx=x \log \left(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+1\right)-\int\frac{2 x^{3/2}+1}{2 \left(\sqrt{x} (x+1)-1\right)}\,dx$$ 
Using $x=y^2$, $dx=2y\,dy$, the new integrand becomes
$$\frac{2 y^4+y}{y^3+y-1}=2y-\frac 23 \frac{3y^2+1}{y^3+y-1}+\frac{3 y+\frac{2}{3}}{y^3+y-1}$$
No problem with the first and the second integrals and
$$\int \frac{2 y^4+y}{y^3+y-1}\,dy=y^2-\frac 23\log(y^3+y-1)+\int \frac{3 y+\frac{2}{3}}{y^3+y-1}\,dy$$  If $a,b,c$ are the roots of $y^3+y-1=0$, partial fraction decomposition leads to 
$$\frac{3 y+\frac{2}{3}}{y^3+y-1}=\frac{9 a+2}{3 (a-b) (a-c) (y-a)}+\frac{9 b+2}{3 (b-a) (b-c) (y-b)}+\frac{9
   c+2}{3 (c-a) (c-b) (y-c)}$$ and integration does not make any problem (except that we shall need to work with complex numbers).

Using the numerical solutions for the roots, what is obtained  for the last integral is
$$-(0.566119 +0.792552 i) \log (y+(0.341164 -1.16154 i))-$$ $$(0.566119 -0.792552 i)
   \log (y+(0.341164 +1.16154 i))+$$ $$1.13224 \log (y-0.682328) $$ and, for sure, the result is a real number (do not forget that $y$ varies from $1$ to $\sqrt n$).

Using $n=100$, the result is $364.248$ while the logarithm of the product is $366.441$.

Since I suppose that you are looking for an approximation, let us make
$$\int \frac{3 y+\frac{2}{3}}{y^3+y-1}\,dy \approx \int \frac{3 y+\frac{2}{3}}{y^3+y}\,dy=-\frac{1}{3} \log \left(y^2+1\right)+\frac{2 }{3}\log (y)+3 \tan ^{-1}(y)$$ which will lead to an underestimate of the "exact" result (but much more workable than the one with the complex numbers).

**Edit**

If you are concerned by large values of $n$, using series expansion, you could have a rather good approximation
$$\log\left(\prod_{j=1}^n\left(j-\frac{1}{\sqrt{j}}+1\right)\right)\approx-n+\frac{1}{n}+n \log \left(n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+1\right)+\log (n)$$ as show below using $n=10^k$.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 k & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 16.0898 & 15.9900 \\
 2 & 366.028 & 366.441 \\
 3 & 5915.63 & 5916.99 \\
 4 & 82113.6 & 82116.0 \\
 5 & 1.05131\times 10^6 & 1.05131\times 10^6
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Addendum**

Not enjoying the last integral, I tried to find $a$ such that
$$\int \frac{3 y+\frac{2}{3}}{y^3+y-1}\,dy \approx \int \frac{3 y+a}{y^3+y}\,dy$$ and it seems that $a=\frac {21}{10}$ is a quite good value.

Then
$$\int \frac{3 y+\frac{2}{3}}{y^3+y-1}\,dy \approx 3 \tan ^{-1}(y)+a \log (y)-\frac{a}{2}  \log \left(y^2+1\right)$$ could be a good approximation for the overall problem.

Comment: Really great solution, thanks! I came across the complex numbers too from the roots of $x^3+x-1=0$ but thought there must be an easier way. You were right in that I was looking for an approximation, since I am trying to model the distribution of primes recursively. The product approximates $\pi(n)(n+1)!$, where $pi(n)$ is the prime counting function. This gives $\pi(n)\approx \frac{n^2\left(n-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+1\right)^n}{e^{n-\frac{1}{n}}(n+1)!}$. The original product seems asymptotically equivalent to PNT, but I'm not sure about the approximation. Thanks again for your very detailed answer!

Comment: @DanielCastle. May I confess that I am pretty happy with what I put in the addendum ? Avoiding the complex numbers would make life easier.

Comment: @DanielCastle. In fact, for the integral up to $\infty$,we can prove that $a=2.08538294256803$. My $\frac {21}{10}$ was not (too) bad !

Comment: Agreed, and using your approximations it appears they do indeed give formulas that are asymptotically equivalent to PNT :D

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$
\log\left(x-\frac1{\sqrt{x}}+1\right)=\log(x+1)+\log\left(1-\frac1{(x+1)\sqrt{x}}\right)\tag1
$$
we can expand
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left(1-\frac1{(x+1)\sqrt{x}}\right)
&=-x^{-3/2}+x^{-5/2}-\frac12x^{-3}-x^{-7/2}+x^{-4}+\frac23x^{-9/2}-\frac32x^{-5}\\
&+\frac74x^{-6}-x^{-13/2}-\frac32x^{-7}+\frac{32}{15}x^{-15/2}+\frac12x^{-8}+O\!\left(x^{-17/2}\right)\tag2
\end{align}
$$
Applying the Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula to $(2)$, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\scriptsize\sum_{k=1}^n\log\left(1-\frac1{(k+1)\sqrt{k}}\right)
&\scriptsize=C+\frac2{n^{1/2}}-\frac7{6n^{3/2}}+\frac1{4n^2}+\frac{41}{40n^{5/2}}-\frac7{12n^3}-\frac{151}{168n^{7/2}}+\frac1{n^4}\\
&\scriptsize+\frac{233}{384n^{9/2}}-\frac{43}{30n^5}-\frac{19}{1408n^{11/2}}+\frac{41}{24n^6}-\frac{37451}{39936n^{13/2}}-\frac{257}{168n^7}\\[9pt]
&\scriptsize+O\!\left(\frac1{n^{15/2}}\right)\tag3
\end{align}
$$
where $C=-2.112822784544141167228959835699141026$. This value of $C$ was computed by extending the series in $(3)$ to $O\!\left(\frac1{n^{25/2}}\right)$ then computing the series and sum at $n=1000$.

Exponentiating $(3)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
{\scriptsize\prod_{k=1}^n\left(k-\frac1{\sqrt{k}}+1\right)}
=e^C(n+1)!&\scriptsize\left(1+\frac2{n^{1/2}}+\frac2n+\frac1{6n^{3/2}}-\frac{17}{12n^2}-\frac{13}{24n^{5/2}}+\frac{85}{72n^3}\right.\\
&\scriptsize\left.+\frac{40}{63n^{7/2}}-\frac{2263}{2016n^4}-\frac{47455}{72576n^{9/2}}+O\!\left(\frac1{n^5}\right)\right)\tag4
\end{align}
$$
where $e^C=0.12089622034028779547061195129100937$

---

**Comparison at $\boldsymbol{n=10}$**
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{10}\left(k-\frac1{\sqrt{k}}+1\right)=8.797\color{#AAA}{9320889435034225}\times10^6
$$
The asymptotic approximation in $(4)$ gives
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{10}\left(k-\frac1{\sqrt{k}}+1\right)\approx8.797\color{#AAA}{8732701425646763}\times10^6
$$

---

**Comparison at $\boldsymbol{n=100}$**
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{100}\left(k-\frac1{\sqrt{k}}+1\right)=1.390288698\color{#AAA}{572423540107556132}\times10^{159}
$$
The asymptotic approximation in $(4)$ gives
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{100}\left(k-\frac1{\sqrt{k}}+1\right)\approx1.390288698\color{#AAA}{436807079042110910}\times10^{159}
$$

---

**Comparison at $\boldsymbol{n=1000}$**
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{1000}\left(k-\frac1{\sqrt{k}}+1\right)=5.18731137265394\color{#AAA}{7330549809570345831696}\times10^{2569}
$$
The asymptotic approximation in $(4)$ gives
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{1000}\left(k-\frac1{\sqrt{k}}+1\right)\approx5.18731137265394\color{#AAA}{1698277002810853161117}\times10^{2569}
$$

Comment: Very nice (as usual) !